# Adding number into array where there is a string results in a string instead of a number

Tags: javascript, json

Basically I am trying to convert my array key value from a string to a number in my JSON object:

```js
form["price"] == "23"
console.log(typeof form["price"]) // string
form["price"] == Number(parseFloat(this.formObject[field.fieldName]))
```

My problem is that after doing this, these are the types :

```js
console.log(Number(parseFloat(this.formObject[field.fieldName]))) // number
console.log(form["price"]) // string, should be number
```

How do I change the key type? This is giving me problems for backend validation of my DTO

Comment: On the first line, is the comparison operator intentional?

Comment: `form["price"] == Number...` is a comparison, not an assignment. It doesn't change the value of `form["price"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to equate a value but not compare. Use `=` instead of `==`

```js
const form = {};

form["price"] = "23";
console.log(typeof form["price"]); // string

form["price"] = Number(parseFloat("23")); // Number(parseFloat(this.formObject[field.fieldName]));
console.log(typeof form["price"]); // number
```